# How to ingest Event Hub event list created by Azure Diagnostics into Azure Data Explorer by subscribing to Event Hub Notifications?

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer, data-ingestion

I have an event hub that emits logs from Azure Diagnostic Settings (specifically from a Function App). These logs are in the form of a list and I would like for them to be ingested into Azure Data Explorer. How do I take this list of events and parse them out in a way to be ingested? Is there a way to do this via ingestion mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ingest through to Event Hub option** in the Azure Data explorer.

After following the steps in this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/create-event-hubs-connection?tabs=get-data,get-data-2#create-an-event-hub-data-connection), I am able to achieve your requirement.

Go to your Azure Data explorer cluster in your Query pane, right click on cluster and click on **Get data**. Then select **Event hubs** in the source.

In next step, give the target table or if you want a new table, you can create here. Give the subscription and event hub details to create the event hub connection.

[image]

In the next step, check the preview of your data and give the type of your data.

[image]

Click on finish and the table will be created. Make sure your connection have **[managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-hub-overview#azure-data-explorer-data-connection-authentication-mechanisms)**. Here I have given System assigned managed identity to my connection.

[image]

Here, I have sent a sample data to the event hub.

[image]

And you can see the data ingested into the Azure Data explorer table.

[image]